# How to create floating menu which effect from left to right

Tags: android, android-layout

Am developing android application which contains floating menu effect from left to right. I have one linear layout when i click any button on some other layout i need to call this linear layout with effect from left to right.

Please help me thanks in advance..

Comment: You can just keep menu layout as invisible object and call it with animation when you need it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just refer the quick menu concept.

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/

Answer (score 1):

It may be helps You [Floating Menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#FloatingContextMenu)